# Puppeteer is unable to take a screenshot

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to take a screenshot with puppeteer.

I had many troubles with Unhandled Promise Rejection errors.
I browsed many forums and topics that suggested many different things, which i applied.

These suggestions ranged from using async function, to using try-catch blocks.

After improvements, this is my final version of the code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getPic() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500});

    process.on("unhandledRejection", (reason, p) => {
        console.error("Unhandled Rejection at: Promise", p, "reason:", reason);
        browser.close();
    });

    try{
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        browser.close();
    }

    await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});
    await broswer.close();
}

getPic();
```

Though, still it does not work and i get this error message:

```
Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\pupp
eteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous>
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> { Error: Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): Target closed
.
    at Promise (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\puppeteer
\lib\Connection.js:198:56)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\p
uppeteer\lib\Connection.js:197:12)
    at Page._screenshotTask (C:\...\pupet test\node_modu
les\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:707:24)
    at <anonymous>
  message: 'Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): Target closed.' } } rea
son: { Error: Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): Target closed.
    at Promise (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\puppeteer
\lib\Connection.js:198:56)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (C:\...\pupet test\node_modules\p
uppeteer\lib\Connection.js:197:12)
    at Page._screenshotTask (C:\...\pupet test\node_modu
les\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:707:24)
    at <anonymous>
  message: 'Protocol error (Target.sendMessageToTarget): Target closed.' }
```

Comment: you have got typo in `await broswer.close();` should be `browser`

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use async await properly

You need to use async-await properly. You are calling asynchronous functions in synchronous way.

Here is the modified code with proper await. Read the code below and see what's wrong.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function getPic() {
    try{ // <-- wrap the whole block in try catch
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch(/*{headless: false}*/);
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.setViewport({width: 1000, height: 500}); // <-- add await here so it sets viewport after it creates the page
      await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
      await page.screenshot({path: 'pic.png'});
      await broswer.close(); // <-- close browser after everything is done
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}

getPic();
```

## Check proxy settings

The error says it is timing out, which means it cannot even load the website. Try to check if the page loads properly on the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. Though i tested your code and now i receive this error:
Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded
    at Promise.then (C:\...\pupet_test\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\NavigatorWatcher.js:71:21)
    at <anonymous>

I do not have any proxy issues and the URL are perfectly accessible in a browser.

Comment: I just figured out that if i use  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
Then the code works. In the code above, {headless: false} was commented, and made the code not run. I have no clue why that is happening but that is another question... Thanks!